# Add custom header when call Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync and DialogContext.PostAsync

Tags: botframework

I use botframework .net sdk. 
May I add custom header when i call Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync and DialogContext.PostAsync?

Comment: Could you clarify the actual scenario/requirement that requires to add custom header to response?

Comment: The short answer is that the connector will strip your message of additional custom headers when you send your message. However there may be an alternate solution if you are trying to send data that does not necessarily have to be in the header itself.

Comment: I use [offline-directline](https://github.com/rainmakerho/offline_dl) and want to check chatbot's message at  [offline-directline](https://github.com/rainmakerho/offline_dl) for security validations. So I want add custom header when chatbot call PostAsync. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I reference [[Question] How can I override Autofac configuration to provide my own custom ConnectorClient?](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4075) .  Use MyConnectorClient inherit from ConnectorClient and registered by autofac. It's worked.